# Dart Deprecated Field on, how do you add an event handler now?

Tags: dart

I have this...

```dart
query("#buttonCenter").on.click.add((event){
  OnButtonCenter(event);
});
```

Dart Editor says the on field is deprecated, I cant seem to find what he "new" way is. Surly I'm just having a bad night, this should be easy to figure out, right?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

```dart
query("#buttonCenter").onClick.listen((event){
  OnButtonCenter(event);
});
```

See [New DOM Event Streams API makes it Easier to Listen to and Capture Events](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/01/new-dom-event-streams-api.html) for more details.